# ruby/rails module based namespacing failure

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm experiencing a failure to understand how Ruby module based namespacing is supposed to work. I've always understood it to be that if you have two classes with the same name you can put one in a module to clarify namespace.

At the moment this doesn't work and I can't see why. In `app/models/something/baz.rb` I have:

```
class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'baz'
end
```

I'm not sure why the table_name assignment is in there. Perhaps because of the fact that this file is nested under `something`?

In `lib/foo/bar/baz.rb` I have:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    class Baz
    end
  end
end
```

I've included, in order, the paths `lib/foo`, `lib/bar` in my autoload_paths config value in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(
  #{config.root}/lib
  #{config.root}/lib/import
  #{config.root}/lib/foo
  #{config.root}/lib/foo/bar
  #{config.root}/app/models/concerns
  #{config.root}/app/services
  #{config.root}/app/controllers/concerns
  #{config.root}/app
)
```

at the console I can successfully reference the `Foo`, `Foo::Bar` modules but when I try to do `Foo::Bar::Baz` I get the usual error

> expected Baz to be defined in lib/foo/bar/baz.rb

now I change that class to be in `lib/foo/bar/baz_thing.rb` and refer to it in console as `Foo::Bar::BazThing` everything works. I've come to the possibly erroneous conclusion that the autoload implementation is mightly confused because there are two classes with the same name.

I've double, triple and quadruple checked names and paths on all of this.

I also read through all the suggested possible alternative/duplicate questions shown when creating this ticket and could find none that addressed my situation closely enough to answer my question.

Can anyone identify where I've gone wrong and why my expectations on module namespacing behavior are incorrect?

This is on ruby 2.2.2 and Rails 4.2.6

Comment: Can you show us your autoloading config ?

Comment: added that, thanks.

Comment: I usually use : #{Rails.root} not #{config.root}

Comment: I spent a few minutes validating that they are actually the same thing. I'm working with a codebase I didn't create and I've only been on for a few months, so I have no real context on why config.root was used here.

Comment: did you try calling it `class Foo::Bar::Baz` instead of nested modules?

Comment: With that namespacing you don't need 'lib/foo' and 'lib/foo/bar' in autoload.

Comment: "I have defined a Baz class in the standard Rails way." - be specific. How __exactly__ is it defined? Post actual file path and actual class definition (you can omit the insides of the class, we only need the namespaces)

Comment: if you cook up a [mcve], you'll get an answer in _minutes_ :)

Comment: I can definitely add the innards of the model. What else is necessary to make this example workable beyond that? Not poking, just asking so I can get it in there.

Comment: @meshpi I'll give your suggestion a try. But my confusion about why the code example didn't work stands. I have workable code currently by changing the non-model class `BazThing` so there's no name collision. That works, but I have this compulsion to understand why the module namespacing in my example doesn't work.

Comment: i don't know about the module namespacing issue but the `table_name` line is irrelevant - that's just telling ActiveRecord to use a different database table name for the model

Comment: Try removing `lib/foo` and `lib/foo/bar` from your auto load path. Check if you can access `Baz` (without the namespace) in your console. Right now `Baz`, `Bar::Baz` and `Foo::Bar::Baz` load same file; Are `"Something::Baz"` and `"Bar::Baz"` the same thing?